# How to test a React Component with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Using the [enzyme-example-jest Github project](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/enzyme-example-jest) I am able to clone the repo and run the tests:

```
git clone https://github.com/lelandrichardson/enzyme-example-jest.git
cd enzyme-example-jest
yarn install
yarn test
```

However, I uncommented line 11 of `Foo-test.js`:

```js
expect(shallow(<Foo />).contains(<div className="foo" />)).toBe(true);
```

So that the file now looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

jest.dontMock('../Foo');

const Foo = require('../Foo');

describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    expect(shallow(<Foo />).contains(<div className="foo" />)).toBe(true);
  });

  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    //expect(shallow(<Foo />).is('.foo')).toBe(true);
  });

  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    //expect(mount(<Foo />).find('.foo').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

And when I run the test I now get this error:

```
yarn test v0.17.8
$ jest
Using Jest CLI v0.8.2, jasmine1
Running 1 test suite...Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
 FAIL  src/__tests__/Foo-test.js (0.931s)
● A suite › it contains spec with an expectation
  - TypeError: Component is not a function
        at StatelessComponent.render (node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:44:10)
1 test failed, 2 tests passed (3 total in 1 test suite, run time 1.281s)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

How do I successfully run this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Foo' is defined with ES6 class syntax but is required with `require` in `Foo-test.js`. Using `import` will fix it.

Replace this

const Foo = require('../Foo');

with this

import Foo from '../Foo';